# Qt creator - make a dynamic interface

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I am working on a small UI with QT Creator and its drag-n'-drop tool (QT Designer). Everything was fine till I realized I had to make some widgets dynamic. For example, I have a checkbox and I want some button to appear only if this checkbox is checked by the user or I would like to change the appearance of another widget when the user clicks on some button.

Is it possible to do it only with QT Designer?

Comment: what's the concrete problem with that? You can dynamically add/remove widgets from parent widget or layouts.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tell that I would like to know if you can define interaction between widgets from the QT Creator tool.

Comment: you're talking about Qt Designer, probably. No, you should write all this dynamic stuff in C++ code.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was talking about. Thx.

Comment: You can use QML to do that too, simpler than doing in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's very limited.

Qt designer have signal&slot editor. Yes, you can connect signal `clicked(bool)` to `setVisible(bool)` slot on button and make button visible only when checkbox is checked (see screenshot).

[image]

But when You need more complex dynamic interface (e.g. creating buttons), designed will not help You.